# How to remove the space in the URL using java?

Tags: java, email

We use the URL for Unsubscribed portion for Bulk Email. Apparently, The email is went to the spam folder. Then the URL contains spaces in two places. Otherwise it can't contain space and works fine. One occurs in the name of the api (i.e api=getOutsideUnsub scribeContact). Another one space is occured in the parameter values (i.e &h 5p8pKsyMi8l0)

For example:

> Click here <http://XXX.XXX.XXX//servlet/ZoniacServlet?api=getOutsideUnsub scribeContact&e66Ve62i57=true&m9UCc1ucRi=634&h2BNp44yL7=184621&h 5p8pKsyMi8l0=0&h2ZNp64yM8=null&h2TNp86wP9=5&h2GQy54sI2=1717> to unsubscribe.

How can I remove the leading and trailing edge of the space in the URL?

Comment: Do you realize that having spaces in the URL is not necessarily the cause that your mail went in junk folder?

Comment: Is the sample code the source of your email? Is it a html email? Is the link in an <a> tag? In your sample it looks like the link is printed as text.

Comment: I have typed the above code is comes from the junk folder. The link is not an <a></a> anchor tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

URLEncoder.encode(String s, String enc)

it will replace spaces with + signs as required.

Comment: Can you clarify more,sorry i can't understand what you told ?

Comment: Clarification: use UTF-8 encoding

Comment: an example of using URLEncoder here http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-send-a-get-request-using-java

Comment: The problem seems to be that the spamfilter inserts spaces. An URL encoding won't help in this case.